# How on topic is the military?

Tags: discussion

A few recent questions have had a lot to do with how some military could/should/would deal with something, or what the implications of some act are in terms focusing on a military or war.

It's been said that politics is war by other means and militaries are certainly relevant to international politics and their budgets and policies occupy attention in many national politics, but the distinction seems important enough that I'm uncertain.

A list of military-ish questions: (I'll sort for what I think is good and bad and format them eventually)

[What exactly is the purpose of the Nuclear Proliferation Treaty when nuclear weapons can be substituted with conventional explosives?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/what-exactly-is-the-purpose-of-the-nuclear-proliferation-treaty-when-nuclear-wea)

[Why does the US not just accept North Korea's nuclear ambitions and attempt to mend relationships?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24304/why-does-the-us-not-just-accept-north-koreas-nuclear-ambitions-and-attempt-to-m)

[Weapons exporting process of the U.S?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24372/weapons-exporting-process-of-the-u-s)

[If the US decided to attack North Korea, would it be viable to conduct a false flag operation to gain pretext?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24323/if-the-us-decided-to-attack-north-korea-would-it-be-viable-to-conduct-a-false-f)

[Why UN has called meeting over North Korea but didn't call on its Chemical Weapons "Export"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/why-un-has-called-meeting-over-north-korea-but-didnt-call-on-its-chemical-weapo)

[Why Aung San Suu Kyi is silent on brutality on Muslim minority in Burma?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24318/why-aung-san-suu-kyi-is-silent-on-brutality-on-muslim-minority-in-burma)

[Why is North Korean behaviour often described as "provocative", even though they clearly want to maintain the status quo?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24288/why-is-north-korean-behaviour-often-described-as-provocative-even-though-they)

[Why are US armed forces inefficient in disaster rescue operations?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24266/why-are-us-armed-forces-inefficient-in-disaster-rescue-operations)

[How to solve NK?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-solve-nk)

[is the USA afraid of Venezuela?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24205/is-the-usa-afraid-of-venezuela)

Answer (score 9):

This is very dependent upon the scope of the question, and how specific the question is about the military. If it is the inner workings of military decisions, narrowed beyond political influences, it would be off topic for this SE.

These aren't the first questions to arise. It is understandable that questions will be presented when major news events happens. For some examples I've participated in:

[Why does the failure of a Trident test matter when we are going to replace it anyway?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/14845/6738)
While the procedures for handling and ensuring the safeguard of nuclear weapons is primarily a Military concern, the potential impacts of mismanaging the program are significant. There are still echoes of the cold war in large government dealings, and the prospect of mutually assured destruction being unreliable or mismanaged changes everyone's political calculus.

[China seizes drone in Philippine waters?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/14012/6738)
Even though it was a piece of military equipment that was taken, this exists within the context of the contentions over the South China Sea. Multiple nations claim sovereignty over the area, and there are frequent political endeavors to keep things calm.

Often, when considering a question that may be an edge case, it is important to determine what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 3):

Nearly all Questions about current military activity should be considered on topic.

Technical questions about the military or Historal Questions about the military do not make a question on topic themselves, but if they apply in some way to the current political landscape, they can be considered on topic.